# Джанго: Админ панель - выбор существующего изображения из папки

Tags: python, django, django-admin

У меня небольшая проблема с выбором и дублем изображений.

Есть модель с полем

```
models.ImageField(verbose_name=('Постер'), blank=False)
```

В папке media лежит папка img, а в ней разные папки с изображениями. Мне не нужно загружать новые изображение на сервер, задача выбрать из существующих. Когда я это делаю, в корневой папке media создается дубликат выбранного изображения. В разных постах может использоваться одно и то же изображение. Я постоянно получаю дубликат выбранных картинок.

Answer (score 0):

vatar = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Аватар', upload_to='media/avatar')
Добавь последний параметр и думаю должно сработать!!

Comment: Это не работает. В первом посте я загружаю картинку image-1. Во втором посте я выбираю ту же картинку и происходит дубль - сохраняется она как image-1_clghaGFJ4G. Как я понял поле ImageField исключительно для загрузки файла на сервер, а не для выбора существующего. Есть поле FilePathField - но оно выводит содержимое папки списком, что не очень удобно. Я ищю способ выбирать через админку существующие на сервере изображения с моделью окна как в ImageField.